# bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect Assertion failed

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm receiving the following error when trying to set up a physics world in my iOS7 Sprite kit project.

```
Assertion failed: (count >= 3), function CreateLoop, file /SourceCache/PhysicsKit/PhysicsKit-4.6/PhysicsKit/Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2ChainShape.cpp, line 35.
```

The strange thing is the code I'm using worked before I added new scenes to my project. I reverted my project back to the last known time that it ran correctly and it still does not work. The project will build once I remove the physics world.

```
(SKNode*) myWorld = [SKNode node];
[self addChild:myWorld];

map = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"background1"];
map.position = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
[myWorld addChild:map];

//Setup physics
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, 0.5);
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

CGRect worldFrame = CGRectMake(map.frame.origin.x, map.frame.origin.y-1150, map.frame.size.width, map.frame.size.height + 2000);

myWorld.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:map.frame];
myWorld.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = wallCategory;
```

The program terminates when it tries to execute…

```
myWorld.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:map.frame];
```

If I put this code into a new project, It works just fine. Any thoughts of what is going on with my project and how to fix it?

Comment: Add symbolic breakpoints for NSException, and see why it is terminating. Also, add a breakpoint at the line that is crashing and look at the values of all the objects you have created. Why have you created worldFrame, if you aren't using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that map is non-nil. The error indicates that there aren't enough vertices (3 minimum) which can only happen with a rect if you pass in a zero rect, either because map is nil or the frame has no width/height.

Comment: I was inadvertantly setting the scale of map to zero in another method. Thanks bro!